# Order (Bourbaki)

Tags: order-theory

Bourbaki define the order in the book "theory of sets" by :
Let $R(x,y)$ be a order relation if :

1) $R(x,y)$ and $R(y,z)\implies R(x,z) $

2) $R(x,y)$ and $R(y,x)\implies x=y $

3) $R(x,y)\implies R(x,x) $ and $R(y,y)$

Why we add the third condition ?

Thank you .

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? That's just how an "order relation" is defined.

Comment: Not every set $x$ needs to be $R$-comparable to itself; but the third condition states that if $x$ is comparable to *anything*, then it is comparable to itself as well.

Comment: The third is reflexivity.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that an order relation is a relation that behaves like $\leq$.  In particular, for any $x$, $x\leq x$ should be true (since it's $\leq$, not $<$).

Now you might ask, why does condition (3) say that if $R(x,y)$ then $R(x,x)$ and $R(y,y)$, rather than just saying $R(x,x)$?  The answer is that the relation $R$ doesn't make sense for arbitrary $x$.  For instance, if $R$ were the relation $\leq$ on real numbers, $R(x,x)$ isn't literally true for *all* $x$, only for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  So condition (3) is written to say that for any $x$ or $y$ that the relation $R$ knows how to talk about (in particular, any $x$ or $y$ such that $R(x,y)$ is true), $R(x,x)$ and $R(y,y)$ are true.

A more modern definition would instead define an order relation $R$ *on a set $X$* to be a relation $R\subseteq X\times X$ satisfying conditions (1), (2), and such that $R(x,x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: The "more modern" definition is less general though, e.g. $R(x,y)\equiv x \subseteq y$ is a partial order a la the definition given in the question, but there is no set $X$ such that $x \subseteq x \iff x \in X$. Such an $X$ would be a "set" of all sets.

Comment: Well, if $R$ itself is not required to be a set, sure (but then you might as well similarly allow $X$ to be a class).

Comment: Agreed, but from the wording of the definition it seems likely that "relation" is being used in the logical sense and not as a set. Skimming through "Theory of Sets", it seems pretty clear that this is Bourbaki's intent (though I skimmed fairly quickly) and that the term "correspondence" is used for a set-theoretic relation.

Comment: There is a difference.  B's definition allows antichains to be empty.  Today's definition  does not allow empty antichains (except for the empty set).